# Reusable button

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create a reusable button by extending the Button class. I am just trying something basic with setting the background color and the text of the button. I am a little confused on where/how to call a init method within the class that extends Button. I know I can set these fields with a style but I am hoping there is a way to do it within the class. I wish to make if conditions within the class to determine if the button will change from transparent, color, shape, and other attributes.

Here is the class,

```
    public class SVButton extends Button {

    public SVButton(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public SVButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SVButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        Button SVColorButton = new Button(getContext());
        SVColorButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
        SVColorButton.setText("Push Me");
    }
}
```

Here is the XML I am calling the customWidget Button,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context="com.example.agar098.atomicdesigndemos.MainActivity">

    <com.example.agar098.atomicdesigndemos.CustomWidgets.SVButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your `init()` method creates a brand new, separate button than the class itself.

Comment: Why don't you call from the constructors? After calling `super` ... call the init... but as @cricket_007 mentioned you should not create new button, but change the current button's properties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were going for.

In other words, you only made a `new Button();` in your class, you didn't actually extend anything.

```
public class SVButton extends Button {
    private Context mContext;

    public SVButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public SVButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public SVButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary));
        this.setText("Push Me");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. When you are not defining in your xml and directly use button like below.**

```
    final SVButton svButton = new SVButton(this);
```

**Below constructor will call**

```
 public SVButton(Context context) {
        super(context); 
init();   
 }
```

**2. When you define button in xml, like below**

```
 <com.example.agar098.atomicdesigndemos.CustomWidgets.SVButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**That time below constructor will call**

```
public SVButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
init();
    }
```